# why the date info of minute was wrong after conversion

Tags: oracle, date-conversion, to-char

I used SQL to convert a date:

```
select date,to_char(date,'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:mm') from process
```

The original date is 12/5/2018 2:41:06 PM
but the conversion result is 2018/12/05 14:12. 
Is my SQL wrong?

Comment: `mm` always renders the same value. It isn't context-sensitive ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`mm` is the placeholder for the month - regardless of the position. So the second `mm` contains the month again.

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A)  the placeholder for minutes is `mi`

So you need: `to_char(date,'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI')`